# iCloud is backing up 68 bytes of my app (a plist file), do i need to set a flag to exclude it from icloud backup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, appstore-approval

I have got my iOS app rejected to App Store because I have stored some images and a SQLite database into Documents directory and have not set a flag to them(exclude sync into iCloud), which has violated the iOS Data Storage Guideline.

Now I have move everything e.g the assets and the database sqlite data into the Library/Application Support/Offline Data and marked everything as excluded to iCloud, using this awesome [StandardPath](https://github.com/nicklockwood/StandardPaths) library

Now when i run the app I still found 68bytes of the data is getting backup to iCloud, and i found out it's the plist file that is located in Library/Preferences/au.com.xxxx.plist (as it's exactly 68bytes)

My questions is, should i set a flag to that plist directory as well? Or it doesn't matter? As i don't want to get rejected again

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743977/ios-is-backing-up-28-0kb-of-some-unknown-data-from-my-app-to-icloud?lq=1) here and the OP manages to get 0kb backup to icloud.

> We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
>   app stores 7.1 MB. To check how much data your app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage
>
> The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the
>   user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc.,
>   should be backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp
>   directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location
>   when the user exits the app.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of
>   your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline
>   use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL
>   objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the
>   corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the
>   corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>
> For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent
>   files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.

Comment: The ways of the App Store reviewers are mysterious, but a single plist file of less than 1 K is probably not a problem, especially if this is user preferences that the user actually wants to be backed up.

Comment: Hi Thilo, thanks for your comment. I opened the plist file and found out it's a flag I have set for the user (NSUserDefaults) to remember download has been finished from the server. So you are right that is actually the user preferences that the user wants to back up. My app has also been approved very soon after i re-submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to backup to iCloud add this method into your app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    const char* filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```